# How to display summary table of errors from build results in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, customization

Can I display the build results in NetBeans in the similar form that Eclipse provides? That is, in a table where every error takes a single row?

Currently, NetBeans is giving me raw unparsed textual output from the Ant build. It has hyperlinks to problematic lines, but it is less comfortable than what I am used to from Eclipse.

Here is the screenshot from Eclipse:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open Window menu and choose Action Items (or click ctrl+6 ).
on the left side, you can choose if you want it to list for the editied file/selected project/ all projects.
you can also define a filter (filter icon on left side of the action items window) and there you can define a filter that lists only compilation errors. open the filter editor and you will see the options.

Comment: Thank you. I'd have never (without reading documentation from cover to cover) figured out it is called 'Action items' in NetBeans.